# Select k highest values from a vector of doubles with repeats

Tags: r

Assume we have a vector x of floating point numbers with repeats

```
set.seed(999) 
x <- unlist(sapply(1:5, function(.) rep(rnorm(1), rpois(1, 4)))) 
x
# -0.281740158905298 -0.281740158905298 1.04778530174241 1.04778530174241 0.270070494348895 0.270070494348895 0.270070494348895 0.304095399122096 0.304095399122096 0.304095399122096 0.304095399122096 -1.87865825782054 -1.87865825782054
```

What is the most convenient way to find the k-th highest value in the vector ignoring the repeats?

For the example vector `x` the result for `k=3` would be `0.270070494348895`.

One idea is to use `table`, and such solutions are described here on Stack:

```
k <- 3
sort(as.numeric(names(table(x))), decreasing = T)[k]
```

However, in these solutions it is necessary to go through casting from `character` to `number`, which results in a loss of precision. Anyone has idea for a better solution?

Comment: `unique` instead of `table`?

Comment: ... what a shame, it is more than obvious... should I remove this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort(unique(x), T)[3]
[1] 0.2700705
```